# JavaFX - Button is not working

Tags: java, button, javafx

Creating a small rpg game Oregon trail based. On controller `IntroController` I'm unable to make a button react inside `handle`, while `LeaderBoardController` works properly.

`IntroController` contains two buttons copied from `LeaderBoardController`.

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public Stage stage;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            this.stage = primaryStage;
            initLayout();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /*
     * initLayout contains the functionality to set up the root and scene of the
     * JavaFX view using the desired FXML file, without the mess in start.
     * 
     */
    public void initLayout() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Working Directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/Intro.fxml"));

            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            stage.setMaxHeight(500);
            stage.setMaxWidth(750);
            stage.setResizable(false);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /*
     * switchScene added to clean up mounts of code in regards to switching a scene usually from an actionevent. Takes in a string 
     * .fxml location and the Stage.
     */
    public void switchScene(String fxml, Stage stage) {
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fxml));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            stage.setMaxHeight(500);
            stage.setMaxWidth(750);
            stage.setResizable(false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("ERROR: Unable to open " + fxml);
            stage.close();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }
}
```

```
public class IntroController implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, Initializable {


    @FXML
    Button mainMenuButton;

    @FXML
    Button exitButton;

    @FXML
    AnchorPane background;

    @FXML
    ImageView picture;

    Main main = new Main();


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        showImage("images/cilantroRiceLogo.png");
    }

    /*
     * handle is used as the primary ActionEvent handler for actions such as
     * "when" something is clicked, "then" do so.
     * 
     * @param ActionEvent event
     */
    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button selected = (Button) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) selected.getScene().getWindow();

    if(selected == mainMenuButton) 
        main.switchScene("fxml/Title.fxml", stage);

    if(selected == exitButton) 
        stage.close();



        background.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                main.switchScene("fxml/Title.fxml", stage);
            }

        });

    }

    private void showImage(String imageName) {
        Image image;

        try {
            image = new Image(new FileInputStream(imageName));

            if (imageName.equals("images/cilantroRiceLogo.png"))
                picture.setImage(image);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO handle exception!!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class LeaderboardController implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>, Initializable {

    @FXML
    Button exitButton, mainMenuButton;

    @FXML
    TableView leaderTable;

    @FXML
    TableColumn rankColumn, nameColumn, difficultyColumn, scoreColumn;

    Main main = new Main();

    private ObservableList<Score> scores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    private Leaderboard leaderboard;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL arg0, ResourceBundle arg1) { 

        leaderboard = new Leaderboard();
        setScores();

        rankColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Score, String>("rank"));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Score, String>("userName"));
        difficultyColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Score, String>("difficulty"));
        scoreColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Score, String>("finalScore"));

        leaderTable.setItems(scores);
    }

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Button selected = (Button) event.getSource();
        Stage stage = (Stage) selected.getScene().getWindow();

        if(selected == mainMenuButton) 
            main.switchScene("fxml/Title.fxml", stage);

        if(selected == exitButton) 
            stage.close();

    }

    /**
     * populates scores with the Scores from leaderboard.scores
     */
    public void setScores() {
        for(Score score : leaderboard.getScores()) {
            scores.add(score);
        }
    }
}
```

#### Intro.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.shape.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller.IntroController">
   <children>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="background" disable="true" onKeyTyped="#handle" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0" style="-fx-background-color: #303030;">
         <children>
            <ImageView fx:id="picture" fitHeight="327.0" fitWidth="446.0" layoutX="176.0" layoutY="25.0" onMouseClicked="#handle" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            </ImageView>
            <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="444.0" layoutY="387.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="239.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7f7f7f;" text="Exit Game">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Magneto Bold" size="29.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button fx:id="mainMenuButton" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="53.0" layoutY="387.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="239.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7f7f7f;" text="Main Menu" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true">
               <cursor>
                  <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
               </cursor>
               <font>
                  <Font name="Magneto Bold" size="29.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

#### Leaderboard.fxml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="750.0" style="-fx-background-color: #000000;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.controller.LeaderboardController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="leaderTable" layoutX="122.0" layoutY="110.0" prefHeight="287.0" prefWidth="510.0" style="-fx-background-color: #666666; -fx-overflow-x: none;" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="103.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="110.0">
        <columns>
            <TableColumn fx:id="rankColumn" minWidth="20.0" prefWidth="49.0" text="Rank" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="nameColumn" editable="false" minWidth="173.0" prefWidth="232.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" text="Name" />
            <TableColumn fx:id="difficultyColumn" editable="false" minWidth="30.0" prefWidth="89.0" resizable="false" sortable="false" text="Difficulty" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="scoreColumn" editable="false" minWidth="90.0" prefWidth="138.0" resizable="false" sortType="DESCENDING" sortable="false" text="Score" />
        </columns>
         <columnResizePolicy>
            <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
         </columnResizePolicy>
      </TableView>
      <Button fx:id="mainMenuButton" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="419.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="239.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7f7f7f;" text="Main Menu" textAlignment="CENTER" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="85.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="426.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Magneto Bold" size="29.0" />
         </font>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
      <Button fx:id="exitButton" layoutX="421.0" layoutY="419.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handle" prefHeight="60.0" prefWidth="239.0" style="-fx-background-color: #7f7f7f;" text="Exit Game" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="21.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="426.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="85.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Magneto Bold" size="29.0" />
         </font>
         <cursor>
            <Cursor fx:constant="HAND" />
         </cursor></Button>
      <Label alignment="CENTER" layoutX="169.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="88.0" prefWidth="410.0" text="Leaderboard" textAlignment="CENTER" textFill="#f5f5f5" wrapText="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="169.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="171.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="Old English Text MT" size="72.0" />
         </font>
         <effect>
            <DropShadow blurType="ONE_PASS_BOX" offsetX="2.0" offsetY="2.0" />
         </effect>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: You don't need to implement `EventHandler` with the controller class. In fact I recommend not doing this until you know exactly what you're doing. `#methodName` attribute values in the fxml work regardless of the method name and don't require an interface to be implemented. All you need to make sure is that the method signature is appropriate. This allows you to use different methods for handling events on different nodes that should execute different code. Also this way you can deal with different event types, which your code does not `onKeyTyped`->`KeyEvent`, `onMouseClicked`->`MouseEvent`

Comment: First of all thank you @fabian for editing the formatting of the question, I really appreciate that. 

I've removed the onKeyTyped KeyEvent, but as for the button whether I try to use if '((Button) event.getSource() == mainMenu)' or if '(mainMenu.onMouseClicked != null)' [while specifying **#handle** in the allotted spot in SceneBuilder], neither of these solutions work for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell with out loading the project. Usually what I'd do is set the Handler in the init method and see if you can get it to trigger.

Another random thing to try is to have your handler using the base Event: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html.

Answer (score 1):

So, this was fixed and caused by Github merging/pulling error. Something between that caused an error and broke those two specific files and by correcting that error it has been resolved.